# How to solve PublishSubject, MutableLiveData, RxJava and Disposable subsriptions in kotlin and java?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, kotlin, android-livedata

**Kotline section**

*1. I have written a BaseViewModel.kt using below configuration.*

```
val ioDisposables: CompositeDisposable
val inputs: PublishSubject<Response<List<X>>>
val outputs: MutableLiveData<Response<List<X>>>

init {
    outputs = rx.toLiveData(inputs, ioDisposables)
}

override fun onCleared() {
    ioDisposables.clear()
    super.onCleared()
}

fun observeOutputs(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<Response<List<X>>>) {
    multipleOwners.add(owner)
    outputs.reObserve(owner, observer)
}
```

*2. The RxMapper holding dynamic bindings for toLiveData() api like below:*

```
fun <T> toLiveData(subject: PublishSubject<T>, disposables: CompositeDisposable): MutableLiveData<T> {
    val data = MutableLiveData<T>()
    val disposable = subject.subscribe({ data.setValue(it) })
    disposables.add(disposable)
    return data
}
```

*3. The LiveDataMapper is for reObserve() api*

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.reObserve(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    removeObserver(observer)
    observe(owner, observer)
}
```

**Java Section - from Fragments class**

*4. Subscribing for outputs in first time*

```
    vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(FlagViewModel.class);
    vm.observeOutputs(this, this::processResponse);
```

**This codes works fine at first time but it populates duplicates set of data from second time. :( :(**

Comment: Have you tried using the LiveData-ReactiveStreams that AndroidX provides instead of making your own `toLiveData` function that creates a new subscription each time and never disposes it? :p

Comment: No I haven't. Could you please explain pitfall of above codes? Or which improvement does androidx contain?